# Beautiful Soup can't extract links

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the links of this webpage: https://search.cisco.com/search?query=iot

Using this code I am not getting anything returned:

```
# Get Html Data from webpage
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags    
tags = soup('a') for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href'))
```

I have tried the `find_all()` method but had the same problem.

Comment: Please, provide the output you are getting.

Comment: Is there a reason for the format of your loop statement. It looks weird to me.

Comment: @ottovon I am getting nothing back. The loop statement is fine. I was just not very clean coping it to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need selenium. It is better to use requests. The page uses an API so request from that

```
import requests

body = {"query":"iot","startIndex":0,"count":10,"searchType":"CISCO","tabName":"Cisco","debugScoreExplain":"false","facets":[],"localeStr":"enUS","advSearchFields":{"allwords":"","phrase":"","words":"","noOfWords":"","occurAt":""},"sortType":"RELEVANCY","isAdvanced":"false","dynamicRelevancyId":"","accessLevel":"","breakpoint":"XS","searchProfile":"","ui":"one","searchCat":"","searchMode":"text","callId":"j5JwndwQZZ","requestId":1558540148392,"bizCtxt":"","qnaTopic":[],"appName":"CDCSearhFE","social":"false"}
r = requests.post('https://search.cisco.com/api/search', json = body).json()

for item in r['items']:
    print(item['url'])
```

Alter parameters to get more results etc.

Comment: I don't understand the code fully yet but it works. Thank you!

Comment: An API should be your first choice for this. They are specifically there to serve you this content. Basically you send your query in the body "query":"iot" . In order to retrieve results in batches you specify the startIndex and then number of results to return as the count argument.

Comment: I suspect there is API documentation telling you the max number of results etc. If not play around to find this. You can then update the body in a loop to retrieve all results.

Comment: Ok great thank you. I will definitely dig into this. Is it really possible to scrape the whole ~ 90 000 search results without using e.g. "Splash" or "Selenium"? As you might have already seen there is a "Load More" button to dynamically load more search results.

Comment: I would think so. Explore what the requests per day limit is and max results per query. The API is specifically for this search query purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like java script render to pages.You can use selenium and beautiful soup to fetch the links.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://search.cisco.com/search?query=iot&locale=enUS")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(a['href'])
```

Output:

```
https://onesearch.cloudapps.cisco.com/searchpage?queryFilter=iot
/login?query=iot&locale=enUS
/login?query=iot&locale=enUS
https://secure.opinionlab.com/ccc01/o.asp?id=pGuoWfLm&static=1&custom_var=undefined%7CS%7CenUS%7Ciot%7Cundefined%7CNA
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/index.html
//www.cisco.com/en/US/support/tsd_most_requested_tools.html
https://apps.cisco.com/WOC/WOConfigUI/pages/configset/configset.jsp?flow=nextgen&createNewConfigSet=Y
http://www.cisco-servicefinder.com/ServiceFinder.aspx
http://www.cisco-servicefinder.com/WarrantyFinder.aspx
//www.cisco.com/web/siteassets/sitemap/index.html    
https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/se/internet-of-things/at-a-glance-c45-731471.pdf?dtid=osscdc000283
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/internet-of-things/overview.html?dtid=osscdc000283
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/internet-of-things/iot-kinetic.html?dtid=osscdc000283
https://www.cisco.com/c/m/en_us/solutions/internet-of-things/iot-system.html?dtid=osscdc000283
https://learningnetworkstore.cisco.com/internet-of-things?dtid=osscdc000283
https://connectedfutures.cisco.com/tag/internet-of-things/?dtid=osscdc000283
https://blogs.cisco.com/internet-of-things?dtid=osscdc000283
https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/community/internet_of_things?dtid=osscdc000283
https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/community/learning_center/training-catalog/internet-of-things?dtid=osscdc000283
https://blogs.cisco.com/digital/internet-of-things-at-mwc?dtid=osscdc000283
https://cwr.cisco.com/
https://engage2demand.cisco.com/LP=4213?dtid=osscdc000283
https://engage2demand.cisco.com/LP=15823?dtid=osscdc000283
https://video.cisco.com/detail/video/4121788948001/internet-of-things:-empowering-the-enterprise?dtid=osscdc000283
https://video.cisco.com/detail/video/4121788948001/internet-of-things:-empowering-the-enterprise?dtid=osscdc000283
https://video.cisco.com/detail/video/3740968721001/protecting-the-internet-of-things?dtid=osscdc000283
https://video.cisco.com/detail/video/3740968721001/protecting-the-internet-of-things?dtid=osscdc000283
https://video.cisco.com/detail/video/4657296333001/the-internet-of-things:-the-vision-and-new-directions-ahead?dtid=osscdc000283
https://video.cisco.com/detail/video/4657296333001/the-internet-of-things:-the-vision-and-new-directions-ahead?dtid=osscdc000283
/search/videos?locale=enUS&query=iot
/search/videos?locale=enUS&query=iot
https://secure.opinionlab.com/ccc01/o.asp?id=pGuoWfLm&static=1&custom_var=undefined%7CS%7CenUS%7Ciot%7Cundefined%7CNA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following the template given in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```